# Installing rpy2 with Docker is unable to find R path

Tags: r, django, docker, dockerfile, rpy2

A Django application using Docker needs to install rpy2 as a dependency. Although I install r-base container and specify it as a dependency, when installing django requirements I keep getting:

```
Collecting rpy2==2.8.3 (from -r /requirements/base.txt (line 55))
  Downloading rpy2-2.8.3.tar.gz (186kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.
```

How can specify inside Docker where the R path is?

My server.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:

  r:
    build: ./services/r

  django:
    build:
      context: ./myproject/
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env-server
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_USER}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - r
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    volumes:
      - ./myproject:/app
```

The Dockerfile for django is:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements /requirements

RUN pip install -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && pip install -r /requirements/test.txt \
    && groupadd -r django \
    && useradd -r -g django django

COPY . /app
RUN chown -R django /app

COPY ./compose/django/gunicorn.sh /gunicorn.sh
COPY ./compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh \
    && sed -i 's/\r//' /gunicorn.sh \
    && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh \
    && chown django /entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod +x /gunicorn.sh \
    && chown django /gunicorn.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The Dockerfile for R is:

```
FROM r-base
```

Answer (score 2):

It was easier to just install r inside the django container. So removing the r container and modifiying the django docker file adding this lines, worked:

```
RUN apt-get --force-yes update \
    && apt-get --assume-yes install r-base-core
```